# Understand this date in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

How do I phrase this date `2018-11-04T14:00:00-07:00`? I got this from the NWS API. I have tried using Date() and other functions.

Comment: Is it in text format?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Yes

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs on [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Not sure what format you're after but try the methods, specifically `toDateString()`

```js
var date = new Date('2018-11-04T14:00:00-07:00');

console.log(date.toDateString());
```